# Are high energy photons a superposition of all the particles they could create?

Tags: particle-physics

### Context

A high energy photon,  like $E_\gamma \geq m_ec^2 + m_{\bar e}c^2$ where $m_e, m_{\bar e}$ is the mass of an electron and positron respectively, can spontaneously create an electron-positron pair.

### Questions

Is there a moment when this high energy particle is both a photon and an electron-positron pair?

More specifically, once a photon is high enough energy that it can turn into massive particles, is it still a photon or is it more like a probability of being a photon or other particle?

### Note

I am reading about stars and my book says that high energy photons need a massive nucleus for the simultaneous conservation of momentum and energy. I feel like adding a bystanding nucleus to my question does not change what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since high energy photons propagate with the same velocity (c) as low energy photons, they cannot be a superposition of a photon and a state involving massive particles.  Placed within a medium including massive charged particles, however, they can interact, and/or scatter which permits them to create particle anti-particle pairs and also slows down their velocity of propagation.

Comment: Then what does is mean that light is a "quantum superposition of excited matter states and pure photons"?